# How top pass multiple parameter in $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to pass 2 parameters in $.ajax call.

Here is my code :

```
function getStatistic6() {

var response;
var allstat6 = [];
var dstart = "01/01/2014";
var dend = "31/03/2014";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_6_Entete',
    data: "start='" + dstart + "'" + " end='" + dend +"'",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        response = msg.d;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
            var j = 0;
            allstat6[i] = [response.Items[i].Date, response.Items[i].Piece, response.Items[i].Tiers, response.Items[i].AmoutHT, response.Items[i].AmountTTC, response.Items[i].Quantite];
        }
        fillDataTable6(allstat6);
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });

    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("error loading statistic 6");
    }
});
}
```

I have an error : "**Invalid JSON primitive: end='31/03/2014'.**"

With one parameter, I do well.

How to pass the 2 parameters?

Comment: use data as json like `{start:dstart,end:dend}`

Comment: I have this error Message "Invalid JSON primitive: 01/2014."

Comment: Try with `data: {"start": dstart, "end": dend }`,The other one is not  valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 data: {start: dstart, end: dend }
```

**EDIT**
Try with:

```
 data: {"start": dstart, "end": dend }
```

Comment: I have this error Message "Invalid JSON primitive: 01/2014."

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as an object as given below

```
function getStatistic6() {

    var response;
    var allstat6 = [];
    var dstart = "01/01/2014";
    var dend = "31/03/2014";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_6_Entete',
        //pass it as an object, jQuery will serialize it for you
        data: {
            start: dstart,
            end: dend
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat6[i] = [response.Items[i].Date, response.Items[i].Piece, response.Items[i].Tiers, response.Items[i].AmoutHT, response.Items[i].AmountTTC, response.Items[i].Quantite];
            }
            fillDataTable6(allstat6);
            $('table').visualize({
                type: 'line'
            });

        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 6");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have this error Message "Invalid JSON primitive: 01/2014."

Comment: @Jayce then the server side is causing the problem... what is the server side code

Comment: 'code' public static List<Statistic_6_Entete> Helper_Statistic_6_Entete(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            ...
   } 'code'

Answer (score 0):

Small correction, remove 's and add "&" between each value.

```
data: "start=" + dstart + "&" + " end=" + dend
```